# How to use gcd barrier in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, barrier

I want to use gcd barrier implement a safe store object. But it not work correctly. The setter sometime is more early than the getter. What's wrong with it?
https://gist.github.com/Terriermon/02c446d1238ad6ec1edb08b607b1bf05

```swift
class MutiReadSingleWriteObject<T> {
        
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.readwrite.concurrency", attributes: .concurrent)
        var _object:T?
        
        var object: T? {
            @available(*, unavailable)
            get {
                fatalError("You cannot read from this object.")
            }
            
            set {
                queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                    self._object = newValue
                }
            }
        }
        
        func getObject(_ closure: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
            queue.async {
                closure(self._object)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func testMutiReadSingleWriteObject() {
        let store = MutiReadSingleWriteObject<Int>()
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.come.concurrency", attributes: .concurrent)
        
        for i in 0...100 {
            queue.async {
                store.getObject { obj in
                    print("\(i) -- \(String(describing: obj))")
                }
            }
        }
        print("pre --- ")
        store.object = 1
        print("after ---")
        store.getObject { obj in
            print("finish result -- \(String(describing: obj))")
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: When you say "the setter sometime is more early than the getter", what do you mean? That `store.object = 1` is happening before the `getObject` calls in the loop before it? Because the dispatch queue you're using to test is concurrent, and the operations can happen in any order.

Comment: the implement of `setter` I use the barrier, It worked queue is the same as get method. So I think. the barrier should execute  closure after the  getter function generate by for loop.  The result should print 100 times nil, then print 'finish result -- 1' @ItaiFerber

Comment: The problem here is that `testMutiReadSingleWriteObject` is using a different queue entirely to execute jobs. You are enqueuing all `store.getObject` calls on the `.concurrent` queue in an `async` way, which just submits the job to be executed at some point on that queue's thread, and _those_ jobs will call `getObject` (which will call into your store's queue). This means that there's no guarantee that any of the `getObject` calls will attempt to run before you reach the call to `store.object = 1`. There is no coordination between the queues.

Comment: (And yes, this type of scenario is very difficult to test! It's hard to ensure 100% correctness because of issues like this.)

Comment: tks, I understand what's wrong with it

Comment: Whenever you create a new queue, it creates its own separate thread for jobs to run on. So `testMutiReadSingleWriteObject` has _3_ threads involved: the `queue` thread, the `store.queue` thread, and the thread the test is getting called from (likely the main thread). There is no coordination between the thread the function is already running on, and the thread used by `queue`. To ensure that the `getObject` calls happen on the same thread as the set, you can either get rid of `queue` altogether, or run `queue.async { store.object = 1 }` — but because it's concurrent, there's no order

Comment: I just saw that your update comment was removed but I hope this still helps.

Comment: @Rob Yes.You are right, so I changed the code. My problem is that the timing of adding the task is not right, not serial or concurrent queue

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the reminder! Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a `DispatchQueue`, whether serial or concurrent, it spawns its own thread that it uses to schedule and run work items on. This means that whenever you instantiate a `MutiReadSingleWriteObject<T>` object, its queue will have a dedicated thread for synchronizing your setter and `getObject` method.

However: this also means that in your `testMutiReadSingleWriteObject` method, the `queue` that you use to execute the 100 `getObject` calls in a loop has its own thread too. This means that the method has 3 separate threads to coordinate between:

1. The thread that `testMutiReadSingleWriteObject` is called on (likely the main thread),
2. The thread that `store.queue` maintains, and
3. The thread that `queue` maintains

These threads run their work in parallel, and this means that an `async` dispatch call like

```swift
queue.async {
    store.getObject { ... }
}
```

will enqueue a work item to run on `queue`'s thread *at some point*, and keep executing code on the current thread.

This means that by the time you get to running `store.object = 1`, you are guaranteed to have scheduled 100 work items on `queue`, but crucially, how and when those work items actually start executing are up to the queue, the CPU scheduler, and other environmental factors. While somewhat rare, this does mean that there's a chance that *none* of those tasks have gotten to run before the assignment of `store.object = 1`, which means that by the time they *do* happen, they'll see a value of `1` stored in the object.

In terms of ordering, you might see a combination of:

1. 100 `getObject` calls, then `store.object = 1`
2. N `getObject` calls, then `store.object = 1`, then (100 - N) `getObject` calls
3. `store.object = 1`, then 100 `getObject` calls

Case (2) can actually prove the behavior you're looking to confirm: all of the calls before `store.object = 1` should return `nil`, and all of the ones after should return `1`. If you have a `getObject` call after the setter that returns `nil`, you'd know you have a problem. But, this is pretty much impossible to control the timing of.

---

In terms of how to address the timing issue here: for this method to be meaningful, you'll need to drop one thread to properly coordinate all of your calls *to* `store`, so that all accesses to it are on the same thread.

This can be done by either:

1. Dropping `queue`, and just accessing `store` on the thread that the method was called on. This does mean that you cannot call `store.getObject` asynchronously
2. Make *all* calls through `queue`, whether `sync` or `async`. This gives you the opportunity to better control exactly how the `store` methods are called

Either way, both of these approaches can have different semantics, so it's up to you to decide what you want this method to be testing. Do you want to be guaranteed that all 100 calls will go through before `store.object = 1` is reached? If so, you can get rid of `queue` entirely, because you don't actually want those getters to be called asynchronously. Or, do you want to try to cause the getters and the setter to overlap in some way? Then stick with queue, but it'll be more difficult to ensure you get meaningful results, because you aren't guaranteed to have stable ordering with the concurrent calls.